# How is the memory managed in text editors?

Tags: memory, memory-management, computer-science

Recently taking a deeper delve into memory in computer science, I came across a thought? How do text editors typically manage their memory? When you insert a character, does the entire rest of the document get copied one unit forward (O(n)) in RAM? Is there some sort of linked list involved? Is there padding around each character to prevent many reallocations?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "typical" text editor.  I think various text editors do various combinations of the items you mention.